# PostgreSQL - Update with JOIN - inner or outer?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I come from SQL Server and I am migrating some T-SQL code to Postgres.

In PostgreSQL, I now have this UPDATE statement (see below).

In there:
`"#reportdata"` is a temporary table
`kwt.Report` is a normal table

This part in the WHERE clause is doing an implicit JOIN. I think that's how they call it in Postgres.

`(cr.campaignid = rp.campaignid AND cr.reportdate = rp.reportdate)`

That is because this couple (campaignid, reportdate) represents a unique logical key in kwt.Report. Also, both columns are not nullable in kwt.Report.
In "#reportdata" both columns can be NULL.

My question is: when I see such an implicit join in an UPDATE statement, I am somehow always not quite sure if it's INNER or OUTER join. I think it's INNER, there's no way this to be OUTER but I just want to be sure.

Could someone please confirm?

I mean, OK, if rp.campaignid is NULL there's no way this condition to evaluate to true, right?

`(cr.campaignid = rp.campaignid AND cr.reportdate = rp.reportdate)`

I am asking this, because I am not sure if comparison with NULL works the same way in Postgres as in SQL Server. As far as I recall, in SQL Server `NULL = a` always evaluates to NULL (not to true (bit 0), not to false (bit 1) but to NULL). Please correct me if this understanding is not right. Is this the same in Postgres?

```
UPDATE kwt.Report cr 
SET 
    impressions = rp.impressions,
    clicks = rp.clicks,
    views = rp.views 
FROM 
    "#reportdata" AS rp
WHERE
    (cr.campaignid = rp.campaignid AND cr.reportdate = rp.reportdate)
    AND (rp.campaignid IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: It is an inner join and as far as I can tell the `rp.campaignid IS NOT NULL` is redundant in your query.

Comment: To my knowledge `NULL = a` is always `NULL` in ***all*** dialects of SQL.  There are subtleties like Oracle treating a zero length strings as NULL *(so nothing can ever equal or not equal `''` either)*, but the `NULL` behaviour remains the same.  *(Also also VERY easy for you to test for yourself...)*

Comment: @peter.petrov . . . The behavior of `NULL` is an integral part of the SQL language.  Databases are remarkably consistent in how `NULL`s are treated.  The only difference think of off-hand regarding an explicit `NULL` is that some databases allow duplicates in keys with `NULL` values for `UNIQUE` constraints and some do not.  Oh, and the default type might vary by database as well, if no other type is spcified.

Comment: What do *you* mean by "implicit join"? The operator acts in a certain way. Whether or how a (inner or outer) join is involved depends on how the operator is *described*. But you don't explain your expectations/description. Anyway what problem are you having with understanding some authoritative (product documentation) description? (See [ask] & the voting arrows re research.) PS It isn't enough to know what = NULL returns (unknown/NULL). You need to know that WHERE keeps rows whose condition evaluates to true. (Whereas CHECK is satisfied by rows whose condition doesn't evaluate to false.)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL:

`A = null` is neither `true` nor `false`

Check this

> ```
> with cte0 as 
> (
>    select '1' as c 
> ), cte1 as
> (
>    select null  as c
> )
> select * from cte0 
>    inner join cte1 on cte0.c = cte1.c
> union
> select * from cte0 
>    inner join cte1 on cte0.c != cte1.c
> ```
>
> ```
> c  | c 
> :- | :-
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c4744f67a6aa3e2023648ee941c1e867)*

Comment: . . In **SQL**, `NULL` is neither true nor false.